# MS access tagging column on import from source

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to bring in the data from two tables into one on an import like this:

```
SELECT * INTO Complaints FROM( 
    SELECT *
    FROM Received2017 
UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM Resolved2017
)
```

However I can't differentiate this data. So ideally I want a column saying "type" where I can tag if it was a received or a resolved depending on which table it was pulled form.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a constant column in your union:

```
SELECT * INTO Complaints FROM( 
    SELECT *, "Received" As [Type]
    FROM Received2017 
UNION ALL
    SELECT *, "Resolved" As [Type]
    FROM Resolved2017
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just at a `which` column:

```
SELECT r.* INTO Complaints
FROM ((SELECT r.*, "received" as which
       FROM Received2017 as r
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT r.*, "resolved" as which
       FROM Resolved2017 as r
      )
     ) as r;
```